# Exporting Floating Table data in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export a database table with some `nvarchar` (not related to the actual problem) and `float` columns (where the problem occurs) to a flat file.

The issue is that when I use the Import/Export Wizard in SQL Server 2008 R2 x64 in order to export the table to a flat file, the float columns get some "weird" behaviour related to rounding/precision.

For example, if the "actual" value stored in the column is 137691869,04 then in the exported file I get 137691869,03999999 instead of 137691869,04.

How can I resolve that problem in order to get the "exact" value in the exported flat file?

Thanks!

Comment: By definition you can't get "exact" values from a float. Floats are approximate datetypes. If you want precision you should use an exact datatype like numeric.

Comment: Yes, but Float(137691869,04) = 137691869,04. That is, the floating point representation of the number 137691869,04 is the same number. The problems is , why if the number is stored as 137691869,04 inside the database table, when exporting I get 137691869,03999999 instead of 137691869,04?

Comment: Because floats are approximate and in sql server those two "values" are the same thing. select 1
where CAST(137691869.03999999 as float) = CAST(137691869.04 as float)

Comment: Dear @SeanLange In fact 137691869,03999999  is "equall", in the floating point sense, to 137691869,04, but in the flat file I need to get 137691869,04.

Comment: As I have said previously, if you want precision then either cast your column during the export or use an exact numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You should use round() when exporting to truncate:

```
SELECT ROUND(137691869.03999999, 2)
```

Will return the value 137691869.04

If you don't like rounding in your version of server, you could try other related functions: TRUNC(), NUMERIC(), DECIMAL()

I does not matter how the number is stored, round affects only the output:

```
SELECT ROUND(137691869.04, 2)
```

Will return the value 137691869.04

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the number is stored as 137691869,04 inside the database table, but when export I get 137691869,03999999 instead of 137691869,04.